# Who is following a hashtag?

Tags: 2013, newsfeed, hashtags

Is there a way to check how many users (or even maybe who) is following a certain hashtag on our 2013 on-premise farm?

Specifically I am referring to the tags used within conversations on the Newsfeed.

[image]

Comment: Aren't hashtags a metadata search feature? I'm only aware of people following items such as sites, pages and documents, not particular tags... Maybe there is a way to search for all items tagged with a particular tag and then see who is following those items, but you should probably restructure your question a bit if that's the case.

Comment: I can follow hashtags used on the Newsfeed conversations. This is where I need the info how many people are following a specific hashtag. Updated he question.

Answer (score 0):

I would try building something with the Search Rest API, although there may be a more suitable alternative, but hopefully this helps.

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='HASHTAG* + path:https://sitecollectionurl/*'&selectproperties='User_Name'
```

You could start by looking through the Social REST API docs.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/social-feed-rest-api-reference-for-sharepoint